# call c++ class by enum member name

Tags: c++

I have a problem when dealing with a large amount of classes that need to be called according to their enum member name.

Basically: I have an application that receives udp packets, containing a PacketID which corresponds to a enum member, let's say LoginHandler.
How can I nicely call that LoginHandler class constructor and public run() function when I only know the number it corresponds to (in my case LoginHandler = 2).
Currently I'm doing this with a switch statement but it feels like things are getting too large XD

```
typedef enum {
    Token = 0,
    LoginHandler = 1, // <- class I want to call e.g.
    DataHandler = 2,
    // etc...
} MsgType;
```

Comment: how about using a map or array with the enum value (int)?

Comment: you mean with the pointer to my class as value?

Comment: Consider https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193786/map-of-functions-vs-switch-statement

Comment: What are you going to do after you construct an instance of whatever class?  Do all the class types have a common base?

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes they do, they all get the data from the packet passed. They just do different things with it afterwards.

Comment: If you allocate each class when packet received, the map/array could store pointers to a static 'create' function on each class, which allocate a new instance.

Comment: yes so pointer to create function or if that's not there then create your own factory classes for each and store them in the map/array. Additionally, for initialization of map, you can also expose a register option if there are different parts of your code which known/own details of individual classes, they could independently define their own factory class and register to your map that way not one piece of code knows about all the classes which is what i believe you want to avoid by getting rid of if/else blocks.